# How to populate the UITableView contents for the first time?

Tags: ios, uitableview, reload

I have a `UITableView` in a `ViewController`. The first time I run my application, table is empty. The table is filled, when I go through other views and I back to the view(which has a uitable). I use following solution, but it does not work. I put this part of code in `ViewWillAppear` and `ViewDidLoad`, but this is not working.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self getthetablecontentfromserver];
        [self.tableView reloadData]; // to reload selected cell

    });
```

Anyone knows how can I populate the content of my table for the first time?
here it is the getthetablecontentfromserver method:

```
-(void)getthetablecontentfromserver{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://exampledomain.com/data"];
    config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        data= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
      ] resume];
}
```

Comment: Are you call any webservices?

Comment: @NimitParekh Yes, I am loading my data from a webservice

Comment: try to put that code in viewDidappear method

Comment: @Mina once your data receive then just reload the table like [self.tblView reloadData];

Comment: @NimitParekh I already called the reload the data after receiving my data in getthetablecontentfromserver method.

Comment: @Mina can please post those code here if possible

Comment: @Mina please update your question with more code so we can figure out what the problem might be. From where should we know what your app has unless we se code? From your saying your table is not refreshing after gets the data and that's why when you go to another controller and back it cals reloadData method.

Comment: Is getthetablecontentfromserver synchronous ? Because if it isn't, probably it's where your problem is

Comment: @SilviuSt I updated my question

Comment: What about your tableView delegate methods? What's in there?

Answer (score 2):

You should put your call to `getthetablecontentfromserver` on a background thread. Once that completes send a `NSNotification` back to the viewController to call `reloadData`.